# error: no matching function for call to 'begin(const unsigned int&)'|

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    constexpr size_t b = 10;
    int arr[b];
    for ( int i = 0; i<b; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = i;
    }
    for ( int x : b)
    {
        cout<<x;
    }
}
```

The code is displayed above.
Why can't I print the contents of an array using the range for loop? When I try to, it gives me an error saying 
error: no matching function for call to 'begin(const unsigned int&)'|

Comment: The algorithm you're looking for to replace the first loop is `std::iota`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why can't I print the contents of an array using the range for loop?

You can; but the range is the array `arr`, not its size `b`:

```
for (int x : arr)
             ^^^
```

Comment: Thanks! Got it!
Anyways, why can't I print b using range for loop?

Comment: Because `b` is not an array or any form of container that can serve as a range. In your mind, read `for (int x: arr)` as "for all integers x that are contained in arr". Replace "arr" with "b" in that sentence and you'll see that that would not make sense.